# How to reset a ViewModel to default values

Tags: asp.net-mvc, knockout.js

I have a object called Index:

```
function Index() {
    var self = this;
    self.name = ko.observable("Kiwanax");
}
```

And I have a ViewModel like this:

```
function IndexViewModel() {

    var self = this;
    var index = new Index();

    self.content = index;
    self.default = index;
}
ko.applyBindings(new IndexViewModel());


//-------------------------------------------
<input type="text" data-bind="text: content.name" />
```

The point is: in some point, I want to reset my form to default values. It means change the current viewmodel values to the default variable values. But I'm not figuring out how to do this.

```
self.resetForm = function() {
    // How to update the current content variable to default variable values?
    // I think in something like that below:

    self.content = self.default;
}
```

Thanks all!

Comment: The screen doesn't update properly. Nothing happens.

Comment: Yeah, I didn't write the whole code. Just an example about what I need to do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a simple js object with default values:

```
function Index(data) {
   var self = this;
   self.name = ko.observable(data.name);
}

function IndexViewModel() {
    var self = this;
    self.defaultData = {name: "Kiwanax"};
    self.index = new Index(defaultData);

    self.resetForm = function() {
        self.index = new Index(defaultData);
    }
}
```

When you call resetForm, you just recreated Index object with default data.

Answer (score 2):

The form doesn't display anything because you should use the value binding with inputs.

As for the default values, my suggestion is to make an extender:

```
ko.extenders.defaultValue = function(target, option){
    target.reset = function(){
        target(option);
    }        
    return target;
}
```

And use it like this:

```
self.name = ko.observable("Kiwanax").extend({defaultValue:"defaultValue"});
```

To reset to default call:

```
self.name.reset();
```

Fiddle with all code: http://jsfiddle.net/25ECB/3/

EDIT: To control a lot of fields, you could use ko mapping and use the create option to add the extender, but I prefer the implementation below, because it allows for an easy resetAll (updated fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/25ECB/6/).

```
function Index() {
    var self = this;
    var lotsOfProps = [
        {
            name:"name1",
            value:"initialValue1",
        },
        {
            name:"name2",
            value:"initialValue2",
        },      
        {
            name:"name3",
            value:"initialValue3",
        }                
        ];

    ko.utils.arrayForEach(lotsOfProps, function(prop){
        self[prop.name] = ko.observable(prop.value).extend({defaultValue:prop.value});
    });
    //self.name = ko.observable("Kiwanax").extend({defaultValue:"defaultValue"});

    self.resetAll = function(){
        ko.utils.arrayForEach(lotsOfProps, function(prop){
            self[prop.name].reset();
        })
    }
}


function IndexViewModel() {

    var self = this;
    var index = new Index();

    self.content = index;

    self.resetForm = function() {
        // How to update the current content variable to default variable values?
        // I think in something like that below:
        self.content.resetAll();
    }
}
```

Comment: Do you know if has a way to add this defaultValue extended property to other properties instead use the syntax you wrote above? My ViewModel is pretty big, and I don't know if is nice write this extender for each property.

Comment: Thanks, @pax162, your solution works fine. But the solution above is cleaner than yours. Thanks!